# rest api consumed from c# desktop application run forever

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a rest api written in asp.net core and deployed on the server that do a relatively long processing (around 15 minutes) then after finishing it return an "ok" status string.

if i run it from a web browser it work without a problem like expected .
it did the job and return "ok" when finished .

but when consumed from a WPF application using httpclient the task is executed but i never get the result back .
it continue to run indefinitely even all the tasks are done (i have checked that) .

here my button click event to start the operation

```
    try
    {
        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;

        savedtime = DateTime.Now;
        // this is used to display a timer on the screen so users know how much time it's taking
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new 
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();


        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {

                await   callserverapi();

        });

        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = true;
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        this.Close();
```

and here the callserverapi function

```
private async Task<string> callserverapi()
{
   var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://myremoteserver.com/Api1");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
    }
    return result;

}
```

also if i use this same code snippet with a remote api that don't take time it work without a problem .

any idea on how to fix this please ?

thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping the call to callserverapi inside the Task.Run?  Just call that method

Comment: because it take time and i am updating a timer textblock on the main ui thread

Comment: You should just be able to call await callserverapi(); in the main method.  If there is a problem updating the UI than marshal that call.